# “Page 6 of those two documents is/are significantly different.”

Tags: grammatical-number

> Page 6 of those two documents **is/are** significantly different.

I think *is* is correct, but what is the rule for this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess it should be something like:

- Page 6 in each of the documents has a significant difference.
- There is a significant difference on Page 6 in each of the documents.
- There is a significant difference between the documents on Page 6.

Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I don't know if 1 ("Page 6 of each document is significantly different") works. I would feel like asking "significantly different from what?" I think 2 ("There is a significant difference of Page 6 in each of the documents") has a problem with the use of the preposition "of": "a significant difference of Page 6" does not sound natural to me. Sentence 3 ("There is a significant difference between the documents on Page 6") sounds good to me; I think it is the best.

Comment: 2nd ought to have been "There is a significant difference on Page 6 in each of the documents.". I corrected the first sentence.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. That sounds a lot better. I still think 3 is best because with the second, I still kind of ask myself "a difference from what?" The third sentence makes it clear that the difference is between the documents.

Comment: @sumelic We are still unclear whether the difference should really be between the documents on the page 6 of each document and something else.

Comment: Sentence 3 is the one that correctly states what I was trying to say. Thanks everyone.

Comment: I would suggest _The pages numbered 6 in each document differ significantly from each other._ To me _There is a significant difference between the documents on Page 6._ means that there is a significant difference between two documents referenced on page 6 of a third one.

Comment: Ben you've got it wrong i guess

Answer (score 2):

I don't think either one works.

I know people often say "just rewrite" when the sentence sounds odd, even if it is grammatical, but I actually think rewriting is the only grammatical option in this case.

"Page 6 of those two documents is significantly different" is potentially grammatical in isolation, but it can't have the meaning you want, because "is different" can't mean "has differences between its different versions".

"Page 6 of those two documents are significantly different" is ungrammatical because "Page 6" is not plural.

This kind of construction is not common because most of the time people use a plural for the first item in similar situations:

> The titles of those two documents are different.

You may have avoided that because it's difficult to pluralize "page 6" (pages 6? page 6's?) but it would be an option if you reword to something like "the sixth pages".

Alternatively, you could make "those two documents" the subject of the sentence and say something like "those two documents are significantly different on page 6".

Comment: Thanks. I am included to agree that neither works and rewording is the only option - but it feels like a cop-out.

Answer (score 1):

Both might be correct, depending on the circumstances. Sumelic's titles show the way, and clarify the dependence on whether or not they are *meant* to be different.

"The titles of those two documents are different" suggests comparison of different documents which, obviously, should have different titles.

"The title of those two documents is different" suggests comparison of copies of the same document which should not, but remarkably do, have different titles - presumably because one is either erroneous or out of date.